# php - use of preg_match or preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
<font size="+1"><font size="+2" color="green"><b>1.</b> 
</font><b>If no head injury is too trivial to be neglected, then:</b></font>
```

In PHP using `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` I want to retrieve the text "If no head injury is too trivial to be neglected, then:"

How can I do this?

Comment: You have read the documentation for those functions and understand what the difference between them is, right?

Comment: Did you come across our [search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search) yet? Questions like that came up before.

Answer (score 2):

**Code :**

```
<?php

$str = '<font size="+1"><font size="+2" color="green"><b>1.</b></font><b>If no head injury is too trivial to be neglected, then:</b></font>';
$pattern = "/font><b>(.+)<\/b>/";
preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches);

echo $matches[1];

?>
```

**Output :**

> If no head injury is too trivial to be neglected, then:

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, under what conditiones you select the string to capture, why gets 1. not captured, but your 2. string does? As long, as you do not explain that I can only guess, so as an expression:

`/<\w+(?:\s+\w+=(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')))*\s*>([^<]+)</\w+>/g`

will match all html tags, that only contain a text node (wich should be case for xhtml, since `<p>text<br /></p>` would not be wellformed...).

so `<p>text</p><br>text2</br>` will be matched and as a result the text will be in capturegroup 1.

`<\w+(?:\s+\w+=(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')))*\s*>` will capture every opening xhtml tag

`([^<]+)` will catch all cahrs exept from < and put it in the capturegroup

`</\w+>` finally catches the closing tag...

the `g` is the global flag so that the expression can catch multiple results...

Good luck with this, if you need something different please be a little more precise...

Answer (score -1):

The pattern will be something like this:

```
/<\s*b\s*>(.+)<\s*\/b\s*>/
```